# VBA - Error handling in a do until loop with Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, vlookup

I have a do until loop that looks for a match in another worksheet and returns a value in yet another worksheet if a given cell matches a criteria.

The code works perfectly okay except for when the criteria is matched but there is no lookup match in the other sheet (this can happen depending on how my data is collected from original sources so it doesnt bother me.)

How do i build an error handler so that if this scenario does happen - i.e. the criteria is matched but no lookup match - then my code just moves onto the next row, i.e the next j

The image is a snippet of my code

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5o4D.jpg]

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: You've gone through more trouble pasting that screenshot than it would have been to paste the code straight from the VBE.

Comment: Also... [Error Handling topic on Docs.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling#t=201611081609371522506) should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
On error Resume Next
```

You could also implement a more specific error handler using something like:

```
On Error Goto ErrorHandler
```

Then in the error handler:

```
ErrorHandler:
'Check the Err.Number value and handle it appropriately
'then do something like
Resume Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim res As Variant '<--| declare a Variant variable to hold the result of VLookups

Do Until j = 26
    If Cells(j, i-1).Value= 0  And ... Then
        res = Application.VLookup(... first VlookUp...) '<--| "try" first lookup and store its result in 'res'
        If Not IsError(res) Then '<--| if Vlookup were successful, go ahead
            Sheets("Main").Range("C" & BlankRow2 + 1).FormulaR1C1 = Application.VLookup(... first VlookUp...)
            Sheets("Main").Range("A" & BlankRow2 + 1).FormulaR1C1 = Application.VLookup(... second VlookUp...)
            Sheets("Main").Range("B" & BlankRow2 + 1).FormulaR1C1 = Application.VLookup(... third VlookUp...)
        End If
    End If
    j = j + 1
Loop
```